# Multiple interval call apis Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem.

When I use interval to call my api again, one of 30 seconds and another of 14 seconds in the first instance it works fine, but later it works like the image, when it should show the following.

Clear A (14 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear B (30 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear B (30 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear B (30 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear A (14 sec)
Clear B (30 sec)
.......
This is my code.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    let exchange = []
    const fetchExchange = async () => {
        const binance = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/binance`)
        const dataBinance = await binance.json()

        const bybit = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/bybit`)
        const dataBybit = await bybit.json()

        const okex = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/okex`)
        const dataOkex = await okex.json()

        const bitget = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/bitget`)
        const dataBitget = await bitget.json()

        const bingx = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/bingx`)
        const dataBingx = await bingx.json()
        exchange.push(dataBinance, dataBybit, dataOkex, dataBitget, dataBingx)
        setExchangeData(exchange)
    }

    const FetchGasTracker = async () => {
        const gas_tracker = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/home/fear_greed`)
        const dataGasTracker = await gas_tracker.json()
        setGasTracker(dataGasTracker[0])
    }
    let a = setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date()
        FetchGasTracker()
        console.log(' Clean a', date.toLocaleTimeString());
        clearInterval(a)
    }, 14000);
    let b = setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date()
        fetchExchange()
        console.log('Clean B', date.toLocaleTimeString())
        clearInterval(b)
    }, 30000);
}, [exchangeData, gasTracker])
```

[Display this process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUeq7.png)

Comment: Why do you use setInterval and then clear it. Why don't use setTimeout?

Comment: `FetchGasTracker` and `fetchExchange` are async functions, but you're calling them synchronously... That's going to mess things up.

Comment: what's the best way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  `[exchangeData, gasTracker]` as your effect deps array which means every time your code sets either `exchangeData` or `gasTracker`, new intervals are registered. This means you likely get more and more timers set ad infinitum since your affect runs `setGasTracker` and `setExchangeData` so that will then cause the affect to run again, which will cause more timers etc.

Did you mean to just use `[]` as the deps array and then allow your interval to run without clearing (you should only clear them in the unmount function, which ive also edited in below)?

```
    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchExchange = async () => {
        const [dataBinance, dataBybit, dataOkex, dataBitget, dataBingx ] = await Promise.all([
        
   fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/binance`).then(res => data.json()),
   fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/bybit`).then(res => data.json()),
   fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/okex`).then(res => data.json()),
   fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/bitget`).then(res => data.json()),
   fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/bingx`).then(res => data.json()),

        ])

        setExchangeData([dataBinance, dataBybit, dataOkex, dataBitget, dataBingx])
    }

    const FetchGasTracker = async () => {
        const gas_tracker = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENDPOINT}/api/home/fear_greed`)
        const dataGasTracker = await gas_tracker.json()
        setGasTracker(dataGasTracker[0])
    }
    let a = setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date()
        FetchGasTracker()
        console.log(' Clean a', date.toLocaleTimeString());
    }, 14000);
    let b = setInterval(() => {
        let date = new Date()
        fetchExchange()
        console.log('Clean B', date.toLocaleTimeString())
    }, 30000);

    return () => {
       clearInterval(a)
       clearInterval(b)
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: I have tried the code and it doesn't work, I get almost the same, the [deps] cannot be empty since I need to update the state to load the new information

Comment: You don't need the deps to contain `exchangeData` and `gasTracker` if you are only *setting* them. You only need it if you *read* from them in the effect. By the way, are you using react strict mode by any chance?

Comment: when it brings the information again, what it does is accumulate in my state, but the information does not update it in the doom, how could I solve that? strict mode is currently enabled.. https://imgur.com/a/Rl03bIK

Comment: Ah this could be a case of the crazy strict mode behaviour in react. In dev, with strict mode, react actually runs the effect twice: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state

Comment: When you say accumulate, do you mean it uses the previous value to calculate the new one (i.e. append, merge or similiar)? If so I dont see that in your code...am i missing something?

Comment: (i see the push to `exchange` but this is a local variable, not the variable defined in deps -- I think theres no need for those deps still). Unless you *are* wanting to append to the state each time, and thats what you mean by its not updating it in the DOM?

Comment: Ah, sorry, its just clicked in my head. Let me edit my answer slightly. You dont want this `exchange` array around, you need to use a setState callback

Comment: Ok cool. Edited answer to no longer require `exchange` local array. However your duplicate timing issue, is quite likely to be related to the strict mode thing...

Comment: Sorry couldn't help myself -- unrelated but Ive made the requests happen in parallel, should make everything go a little faster :)

Comment: Thank very much brother, I change some part and the code run perfectly. change this  `.json()`, to .`then(res => res.json())` and `setExchangeData(prev => [...prev , dataBinance, dataBybit, dataOkex, dataBitget, dataBingx])
    }`  to `setExchangeData( [dataBinance, dataBybit, dataOkex, dataBitget, dataBingx])`

Comment: Great to hear! I edited answer for completeness.